# Could following code be considered strategy pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Could following code snippet be considered strategy pattern? Or it is something else? Or no pattern at all?

```
template <bool bigEndian>
void load(char * buf);

template <>
int load<false>(char * buf) { ... }

template <>
int load<true>(char * buf) { ... }

template <bool bigEndian>
class Loader {
    ...
        // somewhere in code
        int i = load<bigEndian>(buf);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes. I'd say so. Probably shouldn't limit yourself to just `load<bool>` though, could take any `int(*)(char*)`...

Comment: I get what you mean I think. Strategy could be passed as template parameter from outside instead of true/false for big endian? Is that what you mean?

Comment: It certainly looks a lot like a Strategy to me. As an aside, I'd prefer to use something like: `enum order {BigEndian, LittleEndian }; template<> int load<BigEndian>(char *buf) { } template <> int load<LittleEndian>(char *buf) {}`

Comment: In my opinion this is only one more approach to implement the strategy pattern in C++. There are several others, some are listed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964883/strategy-pattern-or-function-pointer/29969095#29969095